# dll not loaded from bin directory

Tags: asp.net, configuration, configuration-files

I have some troubles on using firebird embedded in my application .

if i reference it with the full path in web.config it work

> part of the connectionstring :

```
client library=C:\Dev\WEB\Projects\project1\bin\fbembed.dll;
```

but if i simply put

```
client library=fbembed.dll
```

i have a dllnotfoundexcetion .

i have also checked that the dll and all it's dependencies exists in the Bin folder, and like i said with the full path everything work fine .

any idea please ?

Comment: didnt work :( , i have also tried   ~/Bin/fbembed.dll,  ./fbembed.dll,     ./Bin//fbembed.dll

Answer (score 0):

it wierd but it's solved :)

```
client library=fbembed
```

without ".dll"

*from comments:*

Here it is in context, please note client library=fbembed without ".dll" extension

```
<add name="FBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FBEmbedModel.csdl|res://*/FBEmbedModel.ssdl|r‌​es://*/FBEmbedModel.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;client library=fbembed;initial catalog=|DataDirectory|D2015.gdb;user id=sysdba;password={password};Connection lifetime = 0; Pooling = true; MinPoolSize = 0; MaxPoolSize = 500; Packet Size = 8192; ServerType = 1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: could you please elaborate? what were the steps taken to resolve your issue. Picture someone coming to this page in the future and write for them. Please review [answer]

Comment: <add name="FBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/FBEmbedModel.csdl|res://*/FBEmbedModel.ssdl|res://*/FBEmbedModel.msl;provider=FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;provider connection string=&quot;client library=fbembed;initial catalog=|DataDirectory|D2015.gdb;user id=sysdba;password=masterkey;Connection lifetime = 0; Pooling = true; MinPoolSize = 0; MaxPoolSize = 500; Packet Size = 8192; ServerType = 1&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: please note client library=fbembed without ".dll" extension